# Proportionally resize an IFRAME containing html with flash content in a responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

i have a responsive design with an IFRAME having an html file with flash content inside.

```
<iframe width="800px" height="600px" frameborder="0" align="middle" class="iframeStyle" src="linkToHtmlWithFlash.html"> </iframe>
```

Now i need to resize the IFRAME and its containing flash proportionally as the window width changes.

I have tried it with the combination of `media query` and `transform:scale` like this

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
 .iframeStyle {
    transform: scale(0.74);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}
}
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {
 .iframeStyle {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
}
```

But this method not seems to be so good where it will resize only when the cutoff is reached.

Any solution using jquery or pure CSS?

Is there any solution using pure CSS or jQuery.

Comment: Can't you skip the iframe? Just embed the code you want in your site which gives you much more control in terms of styling.

Comment: @meavo currently it is impossible, bcoz its a big project that was already released and currently running and my challenge is to make it responsive

Comment: The problem is, if your included HTML defines a width or a min-width somewhere it will screw up all your efforts on responsiveness. You could try using something like embed.ly?

Comment: @meavo there is no defined widths in the including htmls, it contains only an swf object

Comment: Ok, in that case all you need to do basically is set a width on your iframe in your media queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
 .iframeStyle {
    transform: scale(0.74);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    width:80%;
}
}
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {
 .iframeStyle {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width:100%;
}
}
```

Use this code i thing useful for you.

use this

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: its not working, `width:100%` will clip off the content inside iframe